# Simple Database Comparison

Tags: c#, database, comparison, oledb

I am trying to compare two databases from different dates. I want to load my 'Orders' table from the `ending` database into a `DataTable`, then convert that `DataTable` to a `Dictionary<string,int>` where string = OrderNumber and int = ClientNumber.

Once I have the Dictionary into memory, I will run my function that goes out to the `beginning` database and performs a `atrOrdersEND.ContainsKey(ordernumber)` check. If it is exists nothing will be done, if it does not exist, I want the information of the `DataRow` to be saved somewhere.

Is this the best way to go about this?

If not, how should I?

```
     static public DataTable getDatabaseInfo(string DB)
            {
                DB = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DB;
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(DB);
                string query = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS;";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {

                }
                return dt;
            }

static Dictionary<string,int> ToDictionary(DataTable DT)
        { //this doesn't work, I get the 'An item with the same key has already been added' error
            var Dict = (from order in DT.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           OrderNumber = order.Field<string>("OrderNumber"),
                           ClientNumber = order.Field<int>("Client")
                       }).AsEnumerable()
                       .ToDictionary(k => k.OrderNumber, v => v.ClientNumber);

            return Dict;
        }

static public void CheckHistoryBEG(string DB)
        {
            DB = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DB;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(DB);

            string query = "SELECT * " +
                  "FROM Orders";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    string ordernumber = dt.Rows[i]["OrderNumber"].ToString();

                    if (atrOrdersEND.ContainsKey(ordernumber))
                    {
                        atrOrdersEND[ordernumber] = atrOrdersEND[ordernumber] + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        atrOrdersEND.Add(ordernumber, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {

            }
        }

public Main()
{
DataTable EndDB_Data = getDatabaseInfo(endDBLocation);
Dictionary<string, int> atrOrdersBEG = ToDictionary(EndDBData);
CheckHistoryBEG(beginningDBLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing any C# code by using linked tables in your MS Access database.  From one DB you can reference the table in the other database.  Then you can do joins or existence queries between the two databases.